# Different batch size different results with inception_v2 during testing

Tags: testing, tensorflow

I user inception_v2 as a base network for classification. During training, the batchsize=128.

During testing, if the batchsize=128, everything is ok. However, if the batchsize is smaller than 128 the results are different. And the precision declines as the batchsize drops. If the batchsize=1, the network will failed. I also used inception_v3 and inception_v1, the same problems appered. However, if the base network is replaced with Alex network (tensorflow), everything goes well. I also replace the inception_v2 with vgg (slim), and everything goes well.

I think the bug is associated with inception_v1~v3 or batch normalization. Maybe I have not used inception_v2 properly. Did anyone encounter similar problems?

*`def net(inputs, num_classes=2, batch_size=128, dropout=0.8, height=224, width=224):
      with slim.arg_scope(inception_v2.inception_v2_arg_scope()):
          end_points = inception_v2.inception_v2(inputs=inputs, num_classes=1001,is_training=True, spatial_squeeze=False)
          kernel_size =inception_v2._reduced_kernel_size_for_small_input(end_points['Mixed_5c'], [7, 7])
          net = slim.avg_pool2d(end_points['Mixed_5c'], kernel_size, padding='VALID', stride=1,scope='avgpool'.format(*kernel_size))
          net = slim.dropout(net, keep_prob=dropout, scope='Dropout_2b')
          end_points['Dropout_2b'] = net
          # regresion layer
      with tf.variable_scope('Regresion') as scope:
          inputchannel = 1024
          stddev = (2.0/inputchannel)**0.5
          logits = slim.conv2d(end_points["Dropout_2b"], num_classes, [1, 1], activation_fn=None, normalizer_fn=None,weights_initializer=trunc_norm    al(stddev), scope='regresion_layer')
      print("inception_v2 finished!")
      return logits, end_points`*

During testing, is_training=False

*restore_list = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if (v.name.startswith("InceptionV2"))]
saver_googlenet = tf.train.Saver(var_list=restore_list) # var_list=restore_list
saver_googlenet.restore(sess, 'inception_v2.ckpt')*

saver_all = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.global_variables(),max_to_keep=20)

Comment: You you please provide us with some code and if you are using a pretrained model, a link to that model?

Comment: I use inception_v2 (slim) [inception_v2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/inception_v2.py). And following is my code:   `code`